# pip install error python3 linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip

I'm using linux mint and can not install the pip from the downloaded script file due to zlib error.

1 ) Tried to reinstall zlib with following command and it is success.

> $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev

2) python3 is installed correctly.

> $ which python3

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

3) Whenever I try to run get-pip.py file following errors are displayed.

> $ python3 get-pip.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

How can I run the script? It has no problem when installing zlib using apt-get.

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer, but consider using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which has zlib by default.

Comment: You can install python 3 pip with `apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Thanks Luis. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to install zlib
apt-cache search zlib
apt-get install zlib